Github.pull.request.base.sha not finding right commit id
I am using git diff command in my gh action workflow to find directory updated in PR
When PR is opened I run this command to find the changes
Git diff —-name-only origin/main origin/feature
And PR is closed I run this command to find the changes between merge commit and main branch last commit.
As per my understanding GitHub.sha is the commit id of pull request merge
Git diff —-name-only github.pull.request.base.sha github.sha
It was working fine until last week but I see strange behavior this week
First git diff command gives me output containing few extra directories which haven’t even altered in the PR
And second command compares the changes between commit of GitHub pull request merge and previous days commit , instead of comparing changes between merge and main commits
And this is intermittent issue , few PRs works perfectly
The only change I can imagine is changing git repo settings to squash and merge
What is the right approach in GitHub action to run git diff when pr is opened vs closed for a pull request event?
and how to always find the right value for GitHub master branch last commit ID? github.pull_request.base.sha does not always provide the right value
Whats better to use github.pull_request.head.sha or github.sha ?

Note your first diff command will only work if feature is up-to-date with main. A better command to use would be git diff --name-only origin/main...origin/feature. Those 3-dots will filter out commits that are only on main that aren't in feature yet. Also, what merge strategy is being used to complete the PRs, and does it sometimes differ?

Yes it can be squash and merge , rebase. These commands should work with all the merging strategies.

"And PR is closed I run this command to find the changes between merge commit and main branch last commit." That will not work with all merge strategies. It will work with merge, and squash, but not for rebase fast-forward, unless the PR had exactly one commit. (This is actually why some people prefer not to use rebase fast-forward for completing PRs.)

Regarding my last comment, perhaps do a spot check of this: "And this is intermittent issue , few PRs works perfectly" to see if the ones that don't work happen to all be PRs that were completed with rebase fast forward, and also had more than 1 commit. It would make sense for those to not work, since you'd be only seeing changes in the last commit of that PR.

Yes rebase and fast forward is the issue , what do you suggest to use for all these different types of PR merge?

hi @TTT , I  updated workflow to use this command instead - git diff --name-only github.pull.request.base.sha github.sha.
it worked as expected but when I actually tried to re run few of the old runs to check if it does the trick , it worked for few runs but I still see same issue happening in few runs.

I think that should work while the PR still exists, as long as the base SHA is the commit ID at the time the PR was created rather than the current tip of the branch. But after the PR is completed, what do those variables represent? (Do they change or remain the same?)

@TTT I ended up doing this , pr open - git diff —name-only base.sha head.sha and pr close - git diff —name-only base.sha github.sha. Because I think when we close pr , your head.sha is gone. It worked for bunch of prs but I saw issue again in one PR. I don’t understand why base sha is not always referred to latest master branch commit , do we always have to make sure that feature branch has all the latest changes from master ? I am still not sure whats the best approach
